# How to find the max value of two variable function in a range?

Tags: calculus

How can I find the maximal value in the range $[-1,1]$ for $x$ and $y$ of the following expression:

$$\sin(\Pi x)(y-3)/2.$$

I tried doing the derivative of both $x$ and $y$, but it seemed there could be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply the maximum of the products $st$ where $s$ lies between $-1$ and $+1$ and $t$ between $-2$ and $-1$. The maximum value is $2$ and it is attained when $s=-1$ and $t =-2$, i.e. $x=-1/2$ and $y=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the function takes the form $f(x)g(y)$ where $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$ and $g(y) = (y-3)/2$, we can handle them independently. However, note that $f(x)$ takes both negative and positive values, and $g(y)<0$  in the given range. Hence, we try to find the $ -(\min -f(x) g(y)) = -(\min -f(x) \min g(y)$. The function $\sin (\pi x)$ takes it's minimum value as $-1$, and the increasing function $(y-3)/2$ achieves it's minimum when $y=-1$. Thus, the maximum value of the function is 2.